# CSS, Hover error (Second Opinion)

Tags: html, css

looks like i have had a long day, bit tired and can't think. Anyway i have a problem in my css, i recently just fixed one error, then added css sprites and implemented it into my menu. The problem is that the hover state of my main menu is being imprinted onto my sub menus.
So body.currentpage #container #nav .mainmenu li ul li, is having a background image put on it from body.currentpage #nav li#menu6 a:hover. The html is located at, http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah. Here is the CSS

```
#nav {
height: 39px;
margin: 0;
width: auto;
margin-bottom: -8px;
}
.mainmenu {
background: url("../index_files/menu.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 39px;
line-height: 30px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 1024px;
}
#nav li, #nav li a {
display: block;
height: 39px;
}
#nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
#nav li ul {
background-color: #F2EAD5;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #CC8930;
color: #2A8AC6;
float: none;
font-family: "Arial";
font-size: 19px;
margin-top: 8px;
opacity: 0.9;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
}
body #nav li#menu1 {
left: 0;
width: 118px;
}
body #nav li#menu2 {
left: 119px;
width: 212px;
}
body #nav li#menu3 {
left: 332px;
width: 161px;
}
body #nav li#menu4 {
left: 494px;
width: 174px;
}
body #nav li#menu5 {
left: 664px;
width: 193px;
}
body #nav li#menu6 {
left: 861px;
width: 166px;
}
body.index #nav li#menu1 a:hover{
background: transparent url(../index_files/menu.jpg) 0 -39px no-repeat;
}
body.index #nav li#menu2 a:hover{
background: transparent url(../index_files/menu.jpg) -119px -39px no-repeat;
}
body.index #nav li#menu3 a:hover{
background: transparent url(../index_files/menu.jpg) -332px -39px no-repeat;
}
body.index #nav li#menu4 a:hover{
background: transparent url(../index_files/menu.jpg) -494px -39px no-repeat;
}
body.index #nav li#menu5 a:hover{
background: transparent url(../index_files/menu.jpg) -664px -39px no-repeat;
}
body.index #nav li#menu6 a:hover{
background: transparent url(../index_files/menu.jpg) -861px -39px no-repeat;
}
body.community #container #nav li ul {
background-color: #AECEAB;
}
body.kids #container #nav li ul {
background-color: #89BAB7;
opacity: 0.8;
}
body.market #container #nav li ul {
background-color: #FFD0CE;
}
body.sundays #container #nav li ul {
background-color: #E7DAB2;
}
body.index #container #nav li ul {
background-color: #E7DAB2;
}
body.contacts #container #nav li ul {
background-color: #E7DAB2;
}
#nav li ul li a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}
div#container div#nav li ul#sundays li {
width: 211px;
}
div#container div#nav li ul#market li {
width: 161px;
}
div#container div#nav li ul#kids li {
width: 174px;
}
div#container div#nav li ul#community li {
width: 193px;
}
#nav ul {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
visibility: hidden;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
z-index: 9999;
}
#nav li:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
.clearFloat {
clear: both;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#nav #holder ul li {
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: looks like you fixed it?

Comment: you have given class in html file on http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah so put . instead of # in your css before menu1,menu2....menu6.

Comment: @karmal @ Dawson woops haven't updated the html side uploading now.

Comment: @karmal @Dawson Rather not he html but just hadn't uplaoded the code to the example website :S

Comment: Also the drop down text is stuffed, but i just haven't fixed that yet. One bug at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this one by changing the selector in this :

```
body.index #nav li#menu2 a:hover {
    background: transparent url(../index_files/menu.jpg) -119px -39px no-repeat;
}
```

to this:

```
body.index #nav li#menu2 > a:hover
```

This way, only `a` elements that are [direct children](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) of `li#menu2` will have the `background` applied.

You'll have to do the same `>` trick to each of the 6 similar rules.

---

You can fix the "stuffed text" with the same idea.

Change this selector:

```
#nav li
```

to this:

```
#nav > li
```

Comment: Not just my stupidity this time, you taught me something! Thanks thirtydot you really handy. Now just to test it.

Comment: Need a little more help making a new question. ie the thing i said i would deal with ...